# How to rotate sprite like 'Fruit Ninja' in 3D with OpenGLes and cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

i want to know how to rotate sprite with OpenGles like fruit in 'Fruit ninja', I am using cocos2d that means i want to rotate CCSprite in 3D with openGLEs.

thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every [CCNode](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_node.html#ad9ed6702ea9e7d893d98d4472bfab98a) has a [CCCamera](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_camera.html) property. You can use that to rotate the node in 3 dimensions.

Comment: @Steffen Itterheim, thanx for your answer. Will it be same as 'Fruit ninja' fruit rotation??? can you provide more detail answer with some code??

Comment: Sorry, I've never played Fruit Ninja. If it is anything fancy chances are that the animation is pre-rendered and not actually performed in realtime.